# Return data when page is still loading

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, monotorrent

I have a TorrentLeech application with ASP.Net MVC 4 and MonoTorrent library. I want to show the progress of downloading. I don't know how can I do that but I just know that page shouldn't stop loading because the action stops working. Can anybody help me?

this is my action but it's still basic:

```
public ActionResult Tr()
{
    MonoTorrent.Common.Torrent t = null;
    t = MonoTorrent.Common.Torrent.Load(@"E:\Downloads\[isoHunt] Men in Black 3 [ENG] 2012 DVDRip XviD-LPD.torrent");
    MonoTorrent.Client.TorrentManager tm = new MonoTorrent.Client.TorrentManager(t, @"E:\Downloads\[isoHunt] Men in Black 3 [ENG] 2012 DVDRip XviD-LPD\", new MonoTorrent.Client.TorrentSettings(0, 60, 0, 0));

    return View();
}
```

Comment: Could you post the code for your controller action? Is AJAX an option for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a controller action which immediately returns a view in which you would show some spinner animation and kick an AJAX request to another controller action that will perform the actual task.

Answer (score 0):

The page WILL stop working if the Load function times out. It'll never reach the return View(); line. Try threading the Load function call and your page should load.

Edit: better yet, if any of those 3 lines times out, it'll fail to load.